# Include specific special-methods in sphinx

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

I have a bunch of classes which use "special-methods":

```
class Foo(object):
   "Foo docstring"

   attr1 = "Attribute!" #: first attribute
   attr2 = "Another Attribute!" #: second attribute

   def __init__(self):
       self.x = 12

   def say_hello(self):
       """
       say_hello(self) -> None

       Issue a friendly greeting.
       """
       print "Hello! x is {0}".format(self.x)

   def __contains__(self,other):
       """Implement ``other in self``"""
       return other == self.x
```

now I would like to generate html documentation for this using Sphinx and autodoc.  How do I tell Sphinx to document `__contains__`?  I tried adding

```
autodoc_default_flags = ['members', 'undoc-members', 'special-members']
```

to `conf.py`, but that also included `__dict__` which I definitely don't want.

Currently, the relevant portions of the `myproject.rst` file look like:

```
.. automodule:: myproject.foomodule
    :members:
    :undoc-members:
    :show-inheritance:
```

**edit** adding

```
.. automodule:: myproject.foomodule
    :members:
    :undoc-members:
    :show-inheritance:

.. automethod:: myproject.foomodule.Foo.__contains__
```

does add documentation of that method, but in a separate section -- Not as part of the `Foo` class documentation.

Comment: @GarethRees -- If you must know, my use case is that the class `Foo` is something of a poor man's ABC.  It's docstrings tell the user what the expected behavior of it's subclasses are and it raises `NotImplementedErrors`.  I want to document `__contains__` so the user knows what `if x in foo_subclass_instance` is expected to mean, but this could just as easily have been a special `__getitem__` method which doesn't behave in a completely standard way.

Answer (score 21):

You can add:

```
:special-members:
:exclude-members: __dict__,__weakref__
```

To the `.rst` file in order to show special members, except `__dict__` and `__weakref__`

Answer (score 15):

What worked for me is adding the ".. automethod:: **methodName**"

directive in the docstring of the class, instead of doing it in the .rst file.

So, you can change "Foo docstring" to

```
"""
Foo docstring

.. automethod:: __contains__
"""
```

Comment: Thank you! It really worked. I added this directive to the `rst`, and it worked fine (I didn't want to mess my class documentation with what is shown in Sphinx).

Comment: There was a bug connected to `special-members`, it was fixed in 1.8 (https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/2401). I filed another bug now, https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/9818 .

Answer (score 11):

The [special-members](http://sphinx-doc.org/ext/autodoc.html) option now takes arguments (this is a new feature in Sphinx 1.2).

So this should work:

```
.. automodule:: myproject.foomodule
    :members:
    :undoc-members:
    :special-members: __contains__
    :show-inheritance:
```

Answer (score 5):

Since Sphinx 1.8, you can use [autodoc_default_options](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html#confval-autodoc_default_options) in `conf.py`. Example:

```
autodoc_default_options = {
    'members': 'var1, var2',
    'member-order': 'bysource',
    'special-members': '__init__',
    'undoc-members': True,
    'exclude-members': '__weakref__'
}
```

> Setting None or True to the value is equivalent to giving only the option name to the directives.

Note that you can give several values in one string: '`__init__,__call__`'.

Answer (score 3):

I'm currently not 100% thrilled with this solution, so I hope someone can come along an improve it.  However, the way I've solved this problem is to do the following:

```
.. automodule:: myproject.foomodule
    :members:
    :undoc-members:
    :show-inheritance:

    .. autoclass:: myproject.foomodule.Foo
        :exclude-members: attr1,attr2

        .. autoattribute:: myproject.foomodule.Foo.attr1 

        .. autoattribute:: myproject.foomodule.Foo.attr2 

        .. automethod:: myproject.foomodule.Foo.__contains__
```

Here I actually need to tell `autodoc` to avoid documenting the class attributes (automatically) and then I need to add them back on explicitly.  The reason is because apparently when you explicitly nest commands, the [explicit ones come first](http://sphinx-doc.org/ext/autodoc.html#confval-autodoc_default_flags).  If I only explicitly say to add `__contains__`, then it shows up before the attributes which I didn't like.