# Make Read the Docs include autodoc documentation for special-members?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, read-the-docs, autodoc

I have a module with two documented global special-members.

Running Sphinx locally creates documentation that includes their docs, but Read the Docs doesn't. It uses the built-in type's documentation instead.

I have tried both styles: `#:` and docstring after the definition. I have read `autodoc`'s documentation multiple times, and the [*Read the Docs* entry on it](http://docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html#my-project-isn-t-building-with-autodoc). I can't figure out what I'm missing, as I don't even see any build errors on *Read the Docs*.

Any ideas?

Comment: can you show the full command you are using to build doc?

Comment: From https://readthedocs.org/projects/argf/builds/3296530/:
`python /home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/argf/envs/latest/bin/sphinx-build -T -b readthedocs -d _build/doctrees-readthedocs -D language=en . _build/html`

Comment: I was going to come in here and tell you the same way you do in `sphynx`, with `#:` immediatly before the member ... but it looks like you have already tried that, so instead have a +1 in the hopes that you get a good answer :)

Comment: Possibly you're using a different version from the one RTD uses.  Looks like there are some bugs with special-members in various releases.  See https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues?q=Autodoc+special

Answer (score 2):

In case you are using Napoleon extension to handle NumPy or Google style docstrings, you can set a configuration flag for this in your conf.py

http://sphinx-doc.org/ext/napoleon.html?highlight=special#confval-napoleon_include_special_with_doc

If I remember correctly there is also a directive for autodoc:

http://sphinx-doc.org/ext/autodoc.html?highlight=member#event-autodoc-skip-member

By implementing this method you have a fine grained choice of which member is going to be included in the docs and which is not.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15903577/include-specific-special-methods-in-sphinx